# Thread too slow. Better way to execute code (Android AndEngine)?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, andengine

I'm developing a game where the user creates sprites with every touch. I then have a thread run to check to see if those sprites collide with any others. The problem is, if I tap too quickly, I cause a null pointer exception error. I believe it's because I'm tapping faster than my thread is running. This is the thread I have:

```
public class grow implements Runnable{

        public grow(Sprite sprite){

        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float radf, rads; //fill radius/stationary radius
            float fx=0, fy=0, sx, sy;

            while(down){
                if(spriteC[spriteNum].active){
                    spriteC[spriteNum].sprite.setScale(spriteC[spriteNum].scale += 0.001);
                    if(spriteC[spriteNum].sprite.collidesWith(ground)||spriteC[spriteNum].sprite.collidesWith(roof)||
                            spriteC[spriteNum].sprite.collidesWith(left)||spriteC[spriteNum].sprite.collidesWith(right)){
                        down = false;
                        spriteC[spriteNum].active=false;
                        yourScene.unregisterTouchArea(spriteC[spriteNum].sprite);
                    }

                    fx = spriteC[spriteNum].sprite.getX();
                    fy = spriteC[spriteNum].sprite.getY();
                    radf=spriteC[spriteNum].sprite.getHeightScaled()/2;

                    Log.e("F"+Float.toString(fx),Float.toString(fy));
                    if(spriteNum>0)
                         for(int x=0;x<spriteNum;x++){

                                rads=spriteC[x].sprite.getHeightScaled()/2;
                                sx = spriteC[x].body.getWorldCenter().x * 32;
                                sy = spriteC[x].body.getWorldCenter().y * 32;

                                Log.e("S"+Float.toString(sx),Float.toString(sy));
                                Log.e(Float.toString((float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((fx-sx),2)+Math.pow((fy-sy),2))),Float.toString((radf+rads)));
                                if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((fx-sx),2)+Math.pow((fy-sy),2))<(radf+rads)){
                                        down = false;
                                        spriteC[spriteNum].active=false;
                                        yourScene.unregisterTouchArea(spriteC[spriteNum].sprite);
                                        Log.e("Collided",Boolean.toString(down));
                                }
                         }
                }    
            }
            spriteC[spriteNum].body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, spriteC[spriteNum].sprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(spriteC[spriteNum].sprite, spriteC[spriteNum].body, true, true));
        }
    }
```

Better solution anyone? I know there is something to do with a handler, but I don't exactly know what that is or how to use one.

Comment: Your logging does as much work as your actual collision detection does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me awhile to figure out how to do it, but an update handler worked very well. I just used a scene update handler. When creating a scene in onCreateScene, implement this code:

```
        scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

                @Override
                public void reset() {         
                }

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
//Whatever you want to update. Any moving or scaling object essentially.
    }
```

Send rphello101 a PM on http://www.andengine.org/forums/ if someone needs more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to synchronize the execution of your "grow" Runnable so that the run() method doesn't interleave with itself when you press the button rapidly, as you noted. You can probably do this with a simple synchronized method or block, but a queue is also a possibility if you require more advanced control.

As for speed, profile it with traceview and find the bottlenecks. As a user commented above, logging can be pretty expensive.

Comment: Synchronizing and removing the logs did help quite a bit, but I can still crash it. Any other ideas?